# Google Chrome не позволяет задать имя скачиваемому файлу

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome

Общая ситуация такова: после клика на ссылку в новой вкладке браузера открывается окошко с файлом, который позже скачивают стандартными браузерными downloader'ами. Реализация основных моментов:

***Получение URL файла:***

```
public getFileObjectUrl = async (route: string, filename: string): Promise<string> => {
    const data = await this.get<any>(route, { asBlob: true });

    const extension = filename.split('.').pop();
    const mimeType = extension === "csv" ? "text/plain" : lookup(filename); 
    // в этом конструкторе вторым параметром как раз и передается имя файла
    const file = new File([data], filename, { type: mimeType ? mimeType : undefined }); 
    return window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
}
```

***Непосредственно открытие вкладки:***

```
const onOpenDocument = async (document: AttachedDocumentModel) => {
    const fileUrl = await Server.getFileObjectUrl(documentUrl(document.Id), document.Name);
    window.open(fileUrl, "blank");
}
```

Метод `documentUrl()` возвращает путь к соответствующему контроллеру.

В браузере Firefox данный метод работает. При скачивании мы получаем файл с тем именем, под которым он был сохранен в БД. В Chrome же получаем сгенерированное имя BLOB-объекта.

На сервере для данного файла проставляется атрибут `Content-Disposition: "attachment"; filename="Имя_файла.pdf"`.

Вопрос: в чем может быть причина подобной привередливости Chrome?

Comment: А при чём тут сервер если у вас блоб создаётся на клиенте? И непонятно зачем на клиенте создавать блоб, неужели нельзя просто открыть серверную ссылку?

Comment: @AlexeyTen BLOB как раз генерится на сервере. На клиенте открывается только ссылка на него.

Comment: Какой из ваших двух кусков кода работает на сервере?

Comment: @AlexeyTen а никакой.  Первый фрагмент кода получает ссылку на файл (BLOB), сам файл генерится на сервере.

Comment: Первый фрагмент у вас получает не ссылку на файл, а сам файл в виде блоба, потом делает из него `File`. Непонятно зачем такие сложности вместо того, что бы просто сразу скачать файл по ссылке `route`

Comment: Ну или можно так https://jetrockets.pro/blog/problem-with-download-file-in-google-chrome